# Rails to_xls in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, excel, rake-task

I am trying to use the rails to_xls gem in my rake task. My code is:

```
tmp_file = Tempfile.new(['export_test', '.xls'])
ToXls::ArrayWriter.new(@logins_report, :name => 'export_test').write_io(tmp_file)
```

I receive an error that says "rake aborted! uninitialized constant ToXls" Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my gem file would not update to the new version. I had to add the "~> 1.0.0" after it and run bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `require 'to_xls'` in your Rake task?

Comment: Yes i tried that and it still threw the same error. I'm sure what else there is to do to get ToXLS to be initialized.

Comment: Can you post the full rake task code? It should start with your `require 'to_xls'`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually figured out the issue. Turns out my gem file would not update to the new version. I had to add the "~> 1.0.0" after it and run bundle install. Now it is working fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you supply your answer below, and accept it immediately? You might end up with a [Self-Learner badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner) one day.